# WSo2 APIM 1.10.0 and DAS 3.0.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I was trying to integrate the APIM 1.10.0 and DAS 3.0.1. Im running a docker-compose having one docker containers for each APIM product profile. I followed the steps to configure the APIM and DAS outlined in the documentation. I made sure that the stat_db connection is configured both in APIM and DAS. I see the following exceptions in DAS logs. Could someone let me know what might be the issue?

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: Analytics Relation created with an empty schema for tableORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE   

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: Analytics Relation created with an empty schema for tableORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST
```

Also it looks like APIM is having trouble publishing the event in the first place. The following is the exception in the APIM logs here is the full stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler.handleRequest(APIMgtUsageHandler.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:322)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-08-15 03:48:10,520] ERROR - APIMgtResponseHandler Cannot publish response event. null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:140)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler.mediate(APIMgtResponseHandler.java:211)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you check if you can see `ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE` table in `Data Explorer` UI?

Comment: Did you see any errors in the logs while you're installing car file?

Comment: Bhathiya, I see that table in the drop down in the DAS Data Explorer UI. But on search of the table returns nothing. Also I did not install the car file, I just followed instructions in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS. Is there anything that needs to be done?

Comment: At step 10, it automatically installs the toolbox. Did you notice any errors in the log while that happens?

Comment: Nope.  I see the following logs ... [2016-08-15 12:26:05,121]  INFO - APIUsageStatisticsRdbmsClientImpl Deploying DAS cApp 'API_Manager_Analytics_RDBMS.car'...
[2016-08-15 12:26:05,231]  INFO - add:jag Saving datasource 'WSO2AM_STATS_DB'...
[2016-08-15 12:26:05,248]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-08-15 12:26:05,248+0000]
[2016-08-15 12:26:05,425]  INFO - add:jag Datasource 'WSO2AM_STATS_DB' saved
[2016-08-15 12:26:05,426]  INFO - add:jag Initialized datasource 'WSO2AM_STATS_DB

Comment: Please check DAS logs.

Comment: No errors in DAS logs as well. Can you please tell me more about the API Manager logs. I think its not able to publish the events 2016-08-15 02:37:59,383] ERROR - APIMgtUsageHandler Cannot publish event. null java.lang.NullPointerException at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:124)

Comment: Can you update the ticket with complete error trace of that NPE?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler.handleRequest(APIMgtUsageHandler.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:322)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnv

Comment: I don't think you can post the entire trace as a comment. So please edit the question, and post it in the question itself.

Comment: Will do in a couple of minutes

Comment: Posted the full stacktrace.. Please review

Comment: I had a look at code. Looks like the configuration object is null. This can happen due to startup errors. Did you see any such errors?

Comment: Like I mentioned I have docker containers running each profile. Do you want me to check the startup logs for das or API manager?

Comment: I checked the container logs for store, publisher, gateway-worker, gateway-manager and das. I dont see startup errors in any of them but for the das. In the das logs I see the following errors. ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: Analytics Relation created with an empty schema for tableORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE   

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} -  Error in executing task: Analytics Relation created with an empty schema for tableORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST

Comment: Error while creating the table : ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE : Error while accessing table ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE : Error in adding records: Table "ANX___8GECXATQ_" not found; SQL statement:
MERGE INTO ANX___8GECxAtQ_ (partition_key, timestamp, data, record_id) KEY (record_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-140]
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.exception.AnalyticsExecutionException: Error while accessing table ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE : Error in adding records: Table "ANX___8GECXATQ_" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: Seems `ANX___8GECXATQ_` table is not created for some reason. It should be automatically created in `ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE` database which you can define in `analytics-datasources.xml`. Can you check that database? Are you using default H2 db or an external one?

Comment: external mysql DB. Any idea about the null pointer exception? Could it be because Im running different product profiles in diff docker containers? Also, the admin dash board does not come up when i try to bring it up in the gateway manager or worker container. It comes up in the publisher container. Could that be the reason? I think the first step in the puzzle is to solve the issue with publishing the events

Comment: I explained NPE above. Did you check the db? Is the table there? We need to check on that first.

Comment: Sorry not sure which comments you are referring to about the NPE. As for the table, ANX___8GECxAtQ_, I see that table created in the ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE schema

Comment: Was the issue resolved? I have the similar issue. No data published. I followed the instructions to the word, but nothing show up in publisher statistics. From different sources, some mentioned that we have to download the .car file? But where is that .car file for apim? The one I got from github failed at deployment. What a mess